# Gitlab CI/CD yml variables for CMake Windows build

Tags: c++, cmake, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I am writing CI/CD pipeline for Windows Gitlab runner installed on my local machine:

```
variables:
  RT_VERSION: "0.1"

build-win64:
  tags:
    - "win64"
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $RT_VERSION
    - mkdir build 
    - cd build
    - cmake ../ -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DRELEASE_VERSION=$RT_VERSION -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
    - cmake --build . --config Release --target package
  artifacts:
    name: "raytracing-$RT_VERSION.zip"
    paths:
      - build/raytracing-$RT_VERSION-win64.7z
    expire_in: 24 hours
```

The corresponding cmake file:

```
if(WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Wall /WX /EHcs")
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror -Wextra")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++1z -pedantic")
endif()

include_directories(. ../output)

add_executable(raytracing
  main.cpp
)

set(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "7Z")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "7Z")

string(TIMESTAMP BUILD_VERSION "%Y.%m.%d.%H" UTC)
message(STATUS "DRAFT VERSION: " ${BUILD_VERSION})

set(RELEASE_VERSION "" CACHE STRING "program version")
if(NOT RELEASE_VERSION STREQUAL "")
  set(BUILD_VERSION ${RELEASE_VERSION})
  message(STATUS "RV: " ${RELEASE_VERSION})
endif()

message(STATUS "VERSION: ${BUILD_VERSION}")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${BUILD_VERSION})
install (TARGETS raytracing RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
include(CPack)
```

The CI/CD job forks fine except of build version:

```
...
  Building Custom Rule D:/Programming/Gitlab/builds/Y3ZUwhN5/0/ktator/raytracing/CMakeLists.txt
  CPack: Create package using 7Z
  CPack: Install projects
  CPack: - Install project: raytracing [Release]
  CPack: Create package
  CPack: - package: D:/Programming/Gitlab/builds/Y3ZUwhN5/0/ktator/raytracing/build/raytracing-$RT_VERSION-win64.7z generated.
...
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=11828 revision=bbcb5aba version=15.3.0
WARNING: build/raytracing-0.1-win64.7z: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory 
ERROR: No files to upload
```

Variable works fine in `artifacts` section and does not work in `script` section. Please help me with this issue.

I also tried to use percent symbol instead of dollar. It did not help.

```
- cmake ../ -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DRELEASE_VERSION=%RT_VERSION% -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Comment: Does using `-DRELEASE_VERSION=$env:RT_VERSION` works? The default script environment on a windows runner is powershell for newer gitlab versions. See [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1309) for a similar issue.

Comment: No, it does not. There is an error:
`CPack error : Problem creating temporary directory: D:/Programming/Gitlab/builds/Y3ZUwhN5/0/ktator/raytracing/build/_CPack_Packages/win64/7Z/raytracing-$env:0.1-win64/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found!
`$RT_VERSION` should be enclosed in quotation marks.

There is a correct gitlab.yml:

```
variables:
  RT_VERSION: "0.1"

build-win64:
  tags:
    - "win64"
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $RT_VERSION
    - mkdir build 
    - cd build
    - cmake ../ -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DRELEASE_VERSION="$RT_VERSION" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
    - cmake --build . --config Release --target package
  artifacts:
    name: "raytracing-$RT_VERSION.zip"
    paths:
      - build/raytracing-$RT_VERSION-win64.7z
    expire_in: 24 hours
```